# Serializing an object to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

How can I serialize an object to JSON in JavaScript?

Answer (score 298, accepted):

You’re looking for [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Examples:

```js
const object = {
    hello: "world",
    "some array": [ 42, 69, 420, 1337, null, true ]
  },
  primitive = false;

console.log(JSON.stringify(object)); // "{\"hello\":\"world\",\"some array\":[42,69,420,1337,null,true]}"
console.log(JSON.stringify(primitive)); // "false"
```

Comment: Using JSON.stringify() with javascript objects containing arrays have a little thing to it. Please check my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423883/parsing-json-array-gives-error

Comment: @uylmz I don’t think this bug exists anymore in 2023.

Answer (score 51):

Download [`https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js), include it and do

```
var json_data = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: Should I really need to include "json2.js"? It seems to works without it.

Comment: @PavelAlexeev No, you don't neet to include `json2.js` anymore, unless you are targetting very old browsers: modern browsers include a native implementation of the `JSON` object. The good thing about `json2.js` is that it will only kick in if no native object is found. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891299/browser-native-json-support-window-json] for a detailed breakdown of browser support.

Answer (score 4):

Just to keep it backward compatible I load Crockfords JSON-library from [cloudflare CDN](http://www.cloudflare.com/) if no native JSON support is given (for simplicity using jQuery):

```
function winHasJSON(){
  json_data = JSON.stringify(obj);
  // ... (do stuff with json_data)
}
if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(window, "JSON") && typeof JSON.stringify === 'function'){
  winHasJSON();
} else {
  $.getScript('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20121008/json2.min.js', winHasJSON)
}
```

Comment: `typeof JSON === "object"` is not a safe check. `if(typeof JSON === 'object' && typeof JSON.stringify === 'function')` will fail if, for whatever reason, `JSON === null`. You’re looking for an existence check. The correct way is `if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(window, "JSON") && typeof JSON.stringify === "function")` (in modern browsers, it would be `Object.hasOwn(globalThis, "JSON")`, but, of course, modern browsers have `JSON`). According to [Edurne Pascual’s comment](/questions/558518/serializing-an-object-to-json/558534#comment13620495_558536), this check is actually redundant.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to work with JSON in Javascript

Having to work with JSON is a common situation in web development, this is why Javascript provides the `JSON` object with its [static methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#static_methods).

**Parsing from string to object**

To parse a JSON string into a Javascript object we can use `JSON.parse()`

```js
let obj = JSON.parse('{"x": 325, "y": 896, "speed": 16.5}')
```

Result:

```js
obj = {
  x: 325,
  y: 896,
  speed: 16.5
}
```

**Parsing from object to string**

Converting a Javascript object to a string it's as easy as the inverse operation

```js
let str = JSON.stringify({x: 325, y: 896, speed: 16.5})
```

Result:

```js
str = '{"x": 325, "y": 896, "speed": 16.5}'
```