# return a php associative array to javascript array

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to return a php associative array to javascript array through ajaxRequest.responseText

Here's what I do.

First in php, I do this:

```
$encoded = json_encode($thisarray);
echo $encoded;
```

If I echo $encoded, I get {"a":"apple,arrow","b":"boy,bank","c":"cat,camp"}

Then in js script,

```
thisarray = new Array();
thisarray = ajaxRequest.responseText;
```

If I alert thisarray, I get {"a":"apple,arrow","b":"boy,bank","c":"cat,camp"}

That's wrong since alerting an array should give error. But in this case, when I alert thisarray, I get the full array!!

Needless to say, I can't call my value out of thisarray, since it is yet defined as an array.

Anyone can tell me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the JSON string in JavaScript to get an object, preferably with the native JSON object of your browser, if available:

```
var thisarray = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);
```

Otherwise you can use the [JSON parser from JSON.org](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) or [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) if you’re already using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks! Em... native JSON object.... that brings another concern. Is JSON.parse cross browser?

Comment: Got the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891299/browser-native-json-support-window-json

Comment: Looks like it only support the latest versions. Is there other solutions that can be used for low-end browsers?

Comment: @Eric Sim: The native implementations of JSON.parse are based on the original parser written by Douglas Crockford.  If you use his script, http://json.org/json2.js, it will create the global JSON object and its methods for you if they aren't already available.

Comment: It's possible (though not recommended) to use javascript's `EVAL()` to 'convert' a JSON string to an array: `var thisarray = eval(ajaxRequest.responseText)`

Comment: @Duroth: You should only do that if you really trust the JSON data. Because `eval` does parses JavaScript and not just the small subset of JavaScript that is JSON.