# How do you export a JQGrid configuration to XML?

Tags: xml, configuration, jqgrid

I have a number of users that need to save off very specific table configurations, which are to be loaded each h time they visit my application.  How would I go about exporting my JQGrid column configuration to XML so that it can be loaded later.

Answer (score 0):

There are only methods `jqGridExport` and `jqGridImport` (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:import_methods) which can be used to save/restore a part of information which you need.

Probably following link [Remember (persist) the filter, sort order and current page of jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015203/remember-persist-the-filter-sort-order-and-current-page-of-jqgrid) gives you some more information which can help you.

Comment: So which method do you think would be the most effective, saving each users configuration into a database via Jimbo's method from your link, or should I use jqGridExport/Import to save to xml, because there is really little information on how to export/import a configuration via xml?

Comment: Probably you should implement your own way. Methods `jqGridExport` and `jqGridImport` can be used only to export some parameters of jqgrid. If your requirements can be solved with `jqGridExport` and `jqGridImport` you should better use these methods, but in reallity you will probabl need to export/import other kind of information. In this case Jimbo's post can be helps you to find an implementation for you.