# jqGrid save state with local json data

Tags: jqgrid

I need to persist the sort, filter and pagination state of a jqGrid that is loading the full data set from the server initially via JSON and then running locally from then on.  I've tried jQGridState but was unable to get it to save anything but nulls (apparently I'm not alone).  I've also tried the solution from [Remember (persist) the filter, sort order and current page of jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015203/) but was unable to get it to even create the cookie.

Has anyone worked through either of these solutions with local data or made something work another way?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using jquery's [cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie).  Here's an example of someone who got it working:

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/Save%20state