# How to initialize a jqGrid with the proper events for row re-ordering (Sortable)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'd like to be able to subscribe to the events that are raised during a Sortable drag and drop operation (New in 3.6 Sortable Rows) as I need to persist this information back to storage. I've tried onstop and onstart from http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#drag_and_drop_rows_between_grids but it seems to only work with drop target being another table.

Thank you,
Stephen

The Columns:

```
var col_names = ['Qty', 'SFC', 'Item Nbr', 'Brand', 'Product', 'Catalog', 'Price', 'UOM', 'Case', 'Remarks', 'Wt.', 'Par', 'Purchased', 'ProductId', 'SortPriority'];
var col_model = [
{ name: 'Quantity', index: 'Quantity', width: 22, sorttype: "number", editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 10, maxlength: 15} },
{ name: 'ProductAttributes', index: 'ProductAttributes', width: 50 },
{ name: 'ItemNum', index: 'ItemNum', width: 50, align: "right" },
{ name: 'BrandName', index: 'BrandName', width: 100 },
{ name: 'ProducName', index: 'ProducName', width: 150 },
{ name: 'Catalog', index: 'Catalog', width: 100 },
{ name: 'Price', index: 'Price', width: 40, sorttype: "number", align: "right" },
{ name: 'UOM', index: 'UOM', width: 30 },
{ name: 'CasePack', index: 'CasePack', width: 30 },
{ name: 'PackageRemarks', index: 'PackageRemarks', width: 80 },
{ name: 'AveWeight', index: 'AveWeight', width: 30, align: "right" },
{ name: 'Par', index: 'Par', width: 25, align: "right", editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 15, maxlength: 15} },
{ name: 'LastPurchaseDate', index: 'LastPurchaseDate', width: 40, align: "right" },
{ name: 'ProductId', index: 'ProductId', hidden: true, key: true },
{ name: 'SortPriority', index: 'SortPriority', hidden: true }
 ];
```

The Grid:

```
favoriteGrid = $('#favoriteGrid');

favoriteGrid.jqGrid({
    url: '/xxx/yyy/',
    datatype: 'json',
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    jsonReader: {
        id: "ProductId",
        cell: "",
        root: function (obj) { return obj.rows; },
        page: function () { return 1; },
        total: function () { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.rows.length; },
        repeatitems: true
    },
    colNames: col_names,
    colModel: col_model,
    pager: $('#favoritePager'),
    pginput: false,
    rownumbers: true,
    rownumWidth: 25,
    rowNum: 1000,
    autowidth: true,
    height: '500px',
    sortable: true, // enable column sorting
    multiselect: true, // enable multiselct
    gridview: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    loadonce: true, // one ajax call per 
    loadui: 'block',
    loadComplete: function () {
        var gr = $('#favoriteGrid');
        fixGridSize(gr);
    },
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        if (id && id !== lastSel) {
            favoriteGrid.restoreRow(lastSel);
            lastSel = id;
        }
        favoriteGrid.editRow(id, true);
    },
    onstop: function (event, ui) {
        alert("onstop");
    }
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#favoritePager',
    { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: false },
    {},
    {},
    {},
    { multipleSearch: true, showQuery: false },
    {}).jqGrid('sortableRows').jqGrid('gridDnD');
```

EDIT1:

The table generated from jqGrid IS sortable, so I think it's a matter of using these jquery functions, after initialization.

```
$('#favoriteGrid').bind("sortstart", function (event, ui) {
    alert("start");
});

$('#favoriteGrid').bind("sortstop", function (event, ui) {
    alert("stop");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a good question!

To catch the results of resorting of the columns you should use `sortable` *as function* instead of boolean `true`:

```
sortable: function (permutation) {
    alert ('permutation=' + permutation.join(','));
}
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SortaleColumns.htm). If you reorder 'Client' and 'Date' columns you will receive the alert message

[image]

The columns 'rn' and 'cb' used internally for row numbers and multiselect checkboxes are first and have indexes 0 and 1. The columns 'Client' has the index 2 and 'Date' has the index 3. To the `permutation` array after the reordering of 'Client' and 'Date' columns will be `[0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

It's important to mention that if you need to set some options of the [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) you should use another format of `sortable` parameter of jqGrid:

```
sortable: {
    update: function (permutation) {
        alert ('permutation=' + permutation.join(','));
    },
    options: {
        opacity: 0.8
    }
}
```

see [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SortaleColumns_.htm):

[image]

**UPDATE**: To monitor the reordering of rows you can do the following:

```
favoriteGrid.jqGrid('sortableRows', {
    update: function (ev, ui) {
        alert ("The row with the id=" + ui.item[0].id +
            " is moved. New row index is " + ui.item[0].rowIndex);
    }});
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SortaleRows.htm). You can get more detailed information about the rows before and after the new position of the moved row with the following

```
favoriteGrid.jqGrid('sortableRows', {
    update: function (ev, ui) {
        var item = ui.item[0], ri = item.rowIndex, itemId = item.id,
            message = "The row with the id=" + itemId +
                " is moved. The new row index is " + ri;
        if (ri > 1 && ri < this.rows.length - 1) {
            alert(message + '\nThe row is inserted between item with rowid=' +
                this.rows[ri-1].id + ' and the item with the rowid=' +
                this.rows[ri+1].id);
        } else if (ri > 1) {
            alert(message +
                '\nThe row is inserted as the last item after the item with rowid=' +
                this.rows[ri-1].id);
        } else if (ri < this.rows.length - 1) {
            alert(message +
                '\nThe row is inserted as the first item before the item with rowid=' +
                this.rows[ri+1].id);
        } else {
            alert(message);
        }
    }});
```

see [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SortaleRows1.htm).

Comment: I don't think I described what I was looking for correctly..sorry.  http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html > New in version 3.6 > Sortable Rows.  Thank you, Stephen

Comment: @SPATEN: Sorry, it was my error. I updated my answer for `sortableRows`.

Answer (score 1):

Current implementation that works is

```
$('#favoriteGrid').bind("sortstart", function (event, ui) {
    // I had no need for this action
});

$('#favoriteGrid').bind("sortstop", function (event, ui) {

    var lista = jQuery("#favoriteGrid").getDataIDs();
    var items = [];

    for (i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        var rowData = jQuery("#favoriteGrid").getRowData(lista[i]);
        items.push({ productId: rowData.ProductId, rowNum: i });
    }

    var fromFolder = $("#favorite-products > a.selected").attr("data-folderId");
    var payload = { FolderId: fromFolder, Items: items };

    $.blockUI({ message: '<h3><img src="../../../../Content/images/busy.gif" /> Saving your sort order...</h3>' });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/xxx/yyy/zzz/",
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#favoriteStatusMessages").html(data)
            $.unblockUI();
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            $("#favoriteStatusMessages").html(errMsg).addClass("ui-state-error");
            $.unblockUI();
        }
    });


});
```