# Can jqGrid support drag and drop rows with local data?

Tags: jqgrid

I am learning jqGrid, hoping to hook it up to a Redis database eventually. As a first step, I'm working with local data. Here is what I've got to use the sortable rows (drag and drop rows within a grid).  The grid shows up and looks fine, the columns are even sortable, but I can't select a row and move it--what am I missing? Is it just because the data is local?

The css and js files are loaded with no problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My First Grid</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#mytable").jqGrid({
      datatype:"clientSide",
      data:[ {"number": 1, "segment":"frontmatter", "name": "chap0"},
             {"number": 2, "segment":"mainmatter",  "name": "chap1"},
             {"number": 3, "segment":"backmatter",  "name": "chap2"},
           ],
      colNames:['Chapter Name', 'Chapter Number', 'Document Segment'],
      colModel:[
              {name:'name'},
              {name:'number', sorttype:'number'},
              {name:'segment'},
              ],
      autowidth:true,
      height:'200',
      sortname: 'number',
      viewrecords: true,
      caption: 'My first grid',
      altRows:true,
  });
});
jQuery("#sortrows").jqGrid('sortableRows');
</script>

</head>
<body>

<table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, jqGrid support [sortableRows](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#sortable_rows) with local data. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/sortalerows1_.htm), which is just the copy of the demo from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9045125/315935), uses jqGrid 4.4.1 and it works.

The code which you posted has two small, but important error:

- You use `jQuery("#sortrows").jqGrid('sortableRows');`, but you created the grid with another `id`: `jQuery("#mytable")`. So you have to change `"#sortrows"` to `"#mytable"`
- You have to move the line `jQuery("#mytable").jqGrid('sortableRows');` **inside** of `$(document).ready(function(){});` block. You current code calls `sortableRows` *before* the grid is created and so it will not work.

Comment: that was the problem! The first was just a typo, but the second problem was my misunderstanding of the demo. Now it works!

Comment: @Tim: You are welcome! The most important, that your code works now.

Comment: That's exactly what I looked for. I see in the example that the checkboxes are unresponsive. Can I still have colums with working buttons?

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy: Could you specify how you define "unresponsive" checkboxes and describe what exactly you need?

Comment: In the example you gave, the "Closed" column contains checkboxes. And in the example, I'm not able to check or uncheck them. What I need, is a one or more column with regular buttons, with something actually happening when I click them, in a sortable JQGrid. For example, a button to delete the row, and some other actions.

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy: Sorry, but it's many *independent* questions. To define checkboxes not disables one should use `formatoptions: { disabled: false}` option of `formatter: "checkbox"`. To make some action on check/uncheck one can use `beforeSelectRow` callback. For example see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditableCheckbox.htm) created for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24239416/315935). One can use `beforeSelectRow` callback for any other content (buttons). For editing one can use `formatter: "actions"` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5204793/315935) for example)

Comment: Is there anyway that I can pass a server side call while ordering ?

Comment: @HappyCoder: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. What you mean? You can set server side call by call of `jQuery.ajax` for example. The request works asynchronously. So one can do everything *on the client side* during waiting of the server response. If the user click on sorting the column in the time then sorting will be done. If you use `datatype: "local"` then the sorting will be done locally and I see no problem. Please don't ask common questions in comments to the answer if your question have no relation to the answer. You should just ask *new question* on the stackoverflow.