# how to get rearranged columns from the database

Tags: jqgrid

I am working on columns drag nad drop its working fine and the new order is also saved in the database but when i again opens the page it shows the pervious order so, how cani achive this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can save `remapColumns` parameter of jqGrid and use the `remapColumns` method to restore the order of the columns. I recommend you to read [the ansewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935) with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage1_.htm) which show how to do this by saving the information in the `localStorage`. You can do the same, but save the information in the database.