# jQgrid change paramaters sent to server

Tags: jqgrid

I am using cookies to load a users previous sorting and paging options. I would like to take those saved values, and set them as the parameters the server receives.

The paramaters I wish to change are as follows, (rows are replaced by max via prmNames)

`/&max=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc`

I have tried using:

```
   $.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
    sidx:"fName",
    sord:"desc",
    page:2,
    rows:10});
```

and variations of:

```
      beforeRequest:function(){
        $('#grid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {
            sidx: "fName",
            sord: "desc",
            page: 2,
            max: 10
        });

    }
```

It changes the value for `page` using  $.extend($.jgrid.defaults... , but I cannot get the other parameters to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need just use `setGridParam` to set parameters of jqGrid which have another names as `sidx`, `sord`, `page` and `rows`.

```
sidx -> sortname
sord -> sortorder
page -> page
rows -> rowNum
```

So the best would be *to create* jqGrid directly with the above parameters initialized from the cookie.

If you would have problem with creation the grid directly with the parameters which you need you can first create the grid with `datatype: 'local'` which will prevent the loading the grid. Then you change the parameters which you need and additionally set `datatype` to the value which you need ('json' or 'xml'). At the end you reload the grid. So the code should be like the following

```js
$('#list').jqGrid('setGridParam', {
    datatype: 'json',
    sortname: "fName",
    sortorder: "desc",
    page: 2,
    rowNum: 10
}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

If you would have problem with creation the grid directly with the parameters which you need. additionally create the grid with `datatype: 'local'` it will prevent the loading the grid

Comment: Can I set the postData using the postData Object from a previous session?
I can also do something like:
`    beforeProcessing:function () {
            grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { postData:postData })
}`

Comment: @Jaym: In general you can, but it's depend from context whether it's correct way or not. I would recommend you to read [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935) which describe how I understand and implement the problem. You can examine the demos which I posted. I hope it will answer on all your questions.

Comment: I was using a technique similar to the question regarding cookies. And as you stated I was having problems since I was reaching the max cookie size. I will try implementing it locally; it looks like the best option. The demo does exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: very annoying that the param name doesn't match the value sent in the form values. thank you for `sidx -> sortname` saved me tons of time. I thought I was losing my mind.

Comment: @timbrown: You are welcome! By the way you can use `prmNames` [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) of jqGrid to **rename** almost any parameter which will be sent to the server. For example `prmNames: {page:"requestedPage", rows: "rowsPerPage", sort: "sortIndex", order: "sortOrder", search: "isSearching"}`.

Comment: @Oleg Can I see all the parameters sent to server side ?

Comment: @ShamseerKSmr: Do you mean "the parameters sent to server side" or "the parameters which could be sent to server side"? To see parameters which currently sent you can use Developer Tools of Chrome/IE (press F12 to start developer tools, choose Network tab end examine the traffic) or other goo free tools like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). You will see full HTTP traffic inclusive the parameters sent to the server and the responses returned from the server.

Comment: @Oleg thank you I am working on jqGrid VideoTutorial in asp.net mvc - first video -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hpt4Ew4ySZk

Comment: @ShamseerKSmr: It looks interesting, but you use **commercial** [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) but I develop **alternative** fork [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) which I provided under MIT and GPL licenses completely free of charge. In general the video is interesting, but I would include even in the first video the information about rowids (see [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal-div)). I'd recommend to add `prmNames: { id: "EmployeeID" }` to use correct rowids. It will be important later for editing.

Comment: @ShamseerKSmr: Additionally, there are some common ASP.NET base settings, which I recommend always to use. You use old version of Visual Studio and I'm not sure which version of ASP.NET and JSON serializer you use. I recommend to use camel conversion of JSON serializer, which are available for all JSON serializer (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17244774/315935)). It's recommended to use `Newtonsoft.Json` even with old ASP.NET MVC (by loading NuGet package) and to initialize it during application startup. It allows to use native JavaScript names (`employeeID` instead of `EmployeeID`)

Comment: @Oleg thanks for  the information, I will use free jqGrid for upcoming tutorials. can I use same code for both of these free and commercial jqGrid ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152602/discussion-between-shamseer-k-smr-and-oleg).