# Is there a way to have navigation properties on both ends of a relationship without getting a self referencing error?

Tags: c#, ajax, json, entity-framework

I have two tables, **MenuItem** and **SearchTerm**. I have a foreign key on **SearchTerm** that is linked to the primary key on **MenuItem**.

I'm using the database-first approach with entity framework.

The result of the above is that the models generated will contain references to one another. This allows me to get all the data I need in a single statement

```
//Where() condition omitted for this example.
IList<MenuItem> menuItems = db.MenuItems.Include("SearchTerm").ToList();
```

This brings back the data I need. The issue I am having is that when trying to return this data through an ajax call, I get an error **Self referencing loop detected** in my response. I understand this happens because it is trying to serialize the json and is unable to do so.

Is there a way I can fetch the data so that it will only include the first two levels (MenuItem, MenuItem.SearchTerms), or is this something I should be setting on my ajax request?

Comment: I'm hoping to avoid the creation of additional view models.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 options to solve this problem.

1. Control json serialization and serialize only required amount of levels [Proper JSON serialization in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244774/proper-json-serialization-in-mvc-4)
2. Disable lazy loading on dbContext [Turn off lazy loading for all entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#lazyOff)