# .Net Filter For Wrapping JsonResult Actions Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I've built a **Web API application** and found an issue (which currently treated badly in my code), the issue summarized in wrapping all `Json` objects which returned from All API actions with custom nodes(roots).

i.e: I have this json (array) response:

```
[
  {
    "Category": "Pages",
    "Users": [
      {
        "ID": "1",
        "Fname": "Foo",
        "Lname": "Bar"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And Need this response:

```
{
  "Object": {
    "Body": [
      {
        "Category": "Pages",
        "Users": [
          {
            "ID": "1",
            "Fname": "Foo",
            "Lname": "Bar"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So here I just wrapped the response inside `{"Object":{"Body": <Response Here>}}`

And this I need it to be applied on all API Json responses of type `Array`.

And for simple Json object response, I need it just to be wrapped like `{"Object": <Response Here>}`

I wrapped the Json response currently in each controller action by this code:

```
 public JsonResult Categories()
 {
   return Json(new { Object= new { Body= GetCategoriesList() } }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Sure this achievement is so bad because I have to repeat this wrapping in each action.

**My Question Is:**

How to create `ActionFilterAttribute` to be called after each action execution to wrap the response as per the above Json sample?

i.e. for creating the filter:

```
 public class JsonWrapper: System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
 {
   public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
   {
   }
 }
```

i.e. for calling the filter:

```
[JsonWrapper]
public class APIController : Controller
```

And also to set the response content type in the same filter `"application/json"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper JSON serialization in MVC 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244774/proper-json-serialization-in-mvc-4)

Comment: You need a **custom json serializer** instead of a filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If suppose here if what you looking for:

```
public class JsonWrapperAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        //Check it's JsonResult that we're dealing with
        JsonResult jsonRes = context.Result as JsonResult;
        if (jsonRes == null)
            return;

        jsonRes.Data = new { Object = new { Body = jsonRes.Data } }
    }
}
```

Here is how you can use it:

```
[JsonWrapper]
public JsonResult Index()
{
    var data = new
    {
        a = 1,
        b = 2
    };
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Result will be:

```
{"Object":{"Body":{"a":1,"b":2}}}
```

Comment: Thanks it's perfect

Comment: What if I need to create different wrapping for Json Object (not array of Json Objects) like just {"Body":{"a":1,"b":2} and keep array the same

Comment: @MoamenNaanou change line `Data = new { Object = new { Body = jsonRes.Data } }` to whatever you like structure.

Comment: @MoamenNaanou it is JsonArray becouse we checked it on JsonResult in here: `JsonResult jsonRes = context.Result as JsonResult; if (jsonRes == null) return`

Comment: I think the use of an attribute will be quite confusing.  Without looking at the code, what happens if you apply the attribute but return a ViewResult etc?

If you insist on using the attribute, there's no need to create a new JsonResult and assign it to the context, just do
`jsonRes.Data = new { Object = new { Body = jsonRes.Data } }`

Comment: @GrayKing test it. I'm open to any improvement. You can edit code in my answer with your changes and comments and i accept it.

Comment: @teovankot didn't know you could do that.  Edit submitted.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent yourself having to repeat wrapping in each action you could either write an extension method which would do the wrapping for you

```
public static class ControllerExtensions 
{
    public static JsonResult WrappedJson(this Controller controller, object data, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
    {
        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new { Object = new { Body = data } },
            JsonRequestBehavior = behavior
        };
    }
}
```

or create a new ActionResult class (and add extension methods to return that)

```
public class WrappedJsonResult : JsonResult
{
    public new object Data
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.Data == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return (object) ((dynamic) base.Data).Object.Body;
        }

        set { base.Data = new {Object = new {Body = value}}; }
    }
}
```