# refresh grid using inlineNav

Tags: jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I am using inlineNav as follows:

```
var inlineparams = { 
    addParams: {useFormatter:false},
    editParams: {extraparam: { 
                 "action": "ajaxgrid",
                 "subaction": "jqedit", 
                 "tableid": "sysbuglist",
                 "sessionid":"fd7c74d8-d3cb-102f-bd56-0015171f0bcc" 
             }},
    add:true,
    edit:true,
    save:true,
    cancel:true,
    aftersavefunc:reloadGrid};

$("#navgrid").jqGrid("inlineNav","#navgrid_bottompager", inlineparams);
```

So, I am using the add, edit, save, cancel buttons on the bottompager.

Question: How do I get control after a save to the server? Saving to the server is working well, I just want to refresh the grid after a save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [source code for inline editing](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.inlinedit.js), you can see that there is no explicit `aftersavefunc` for `inlineNav`, either in the options or in the save button's callback:

```
if(o.save) {
    $($t).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', elem,{
        ...
        onClickButton : function () {
            var sr = $t.p.savedRow[0].id;
            if(sr) {
                ...
                if( $($t).jqGrid('saveRow', sr, o.editParams) ) {
                    $($t).jqGrid('showAddEditButtons');
                }
            } 
        }
```

However, you can pass `aftersavefunc` as part of `editParams`:

```
var inlineparams = { 
    addParams: {useFormatter:false},
    editParams: {extraparam: { 
                     "action": "ajaxgrid",
                     "subaction": "jqedit", 
                     "tableid": "sysbuglist",
                     "sessionid":"fd7c74d8-d3cb-102f-bd56-0015171f0bcc"},
                 aftersavefunc: reloadGrid},
    ...
```

That should do it. Just be aware that `aftersavefunc` will be invoked on `edit` as well as `save`, since both operations support this callback.

Comment: @GregNeid - Since you just created your account today... you should consider marking this as the accepted answer if it solved your problem. That way everyone else on SO knows that your question has been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: @JustinEthier: You are welcome! Did you already seen that jqGrid 4.3.2 is [published](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) today?

Comment: @Oleg - No, thanks for the update. Do you know if there are any examples for the *New event system*?

Comment: @JustinEthier: The changed were introduced based on [my suggestion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/usage-of-jquery-events-in-jqgrid-together-with-callback-functions-used-currently/#p25559). An example from the suggestion is [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchingToolbarSynchronization.htm). I will later modify the code of the demo and post some other examples which uses the feature. For example I plan rewrite example from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935) with the usage of new events.

Comment: I loved the pdf from 2009.  Anything like that planned for documentation?  The grid is amazing and totally changes my approach to web development.

Comment: @GregNeid - Do not believe another PDF is planned although I am not the person to ask. I find that most everything can be found on the wiki: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs . Although sometimes you have to dig into the code. Also, this link from Oleg explains accepting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235