# Use Of afterSaveCell in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am use Jqgrid.
in which i use afterSaveCell Even. But in this even function can not call.so What's Problem Please Tell me.
My Code

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid(
{
....
editurl:"editMedicineGridData.html",
onCellSelect : function(rowid, iCol, cellcontent) {
 ..
},
gridComplete: function(){ 
 calculateTotal();
},                                          afterSaveCell: function (rowid, name, val, iRow, iCol) {
 alert("After Save Cell");
 calculateTotal();
}
```

In this Code onCellSelect and gridComplete is Working but afterSaveCell is not working 
I am use jqgrid 4.4.1 .
please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't posted more full code of jqGrid which you use, so I can only guess what you do. I suppose that you use editing mode *other as cell editing*. The callback [afterSaveCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) can be used only with respect of cell editing and not with inline editing of form editing.

Comment: I am Use Inline function. In which I am change Quantity save them and now I want to as per Quantity change amount is change and also I want use Total of amount in Footer so How it is Possible.

Comment: @AshuMehta: You can use `aftersavefunc` callback of inline editing functions. If you use `inlineNav` you should place `aftersavefunc` callback inside of `editParams` and inside of `addRowParams` of `addParams`.

Comment: Ur Answer [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089165/refresh-grid-using-inlinenav) Like this. i want Calculate function which is used in LoadComplete Event.How to use in inline nav

Comment: @AshuMehta: Sorry, but I have to make my main job and not create only different demos and answer on the questions on the stackoverflow. I posted you already code example and some links in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13227472/315935) on your previous question.