# Total Of Amount in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am Use jqGrid.

```
$("#list").jqgrid(){
    ....
    editurl:"editMedicineGridData.html",
    onCellSelect : function(rowid, iCol, cellcontent) {
        $('#prescribedDate').val(jQuery("#madicineGrid").jqGrid('getCell',rowid, 'PrescriptionDate'));
    },
    gridComplete: function(){ 
        var grid = $("#madicineGrid"),
            sum = grid.jqGrid('getCol','totalAmount', false, 'sum');
        $('#totalMedicineCharge').html(sum);
    },
    ondblClickRow: function (rowid,name,val,iRow,iCol) {
        $(this).jqGrid('editRow', rowid, true, null, null, null, {}, function (rowid) {
        });
    },
    afterSaveCell : function(rowid,name,val,iRow,iCol) {
        if(name == 'SaleQuantity') {
            var Qval = jQuery("#madicineGrid").jqGrid('getCell',rowid,iCol+1);
            var Aval = jQuery("#madicineGrid").jqGrid('getCell',rowid,iCol);
            jQuery("#madicineGrid").jqGrid('setRowData',rowid,{totalAmount: parseFloat(Aval) * parseFloat(Qval)});
        }
        var grid = $("#madicineGrid"),
            sum = grid.jqGrid('getCol','totalAmount', false, 'sum');
       $('#totalMedicineCharge').html(sum);
    } 
});
```

so I want Update my data and Change it.
My Problem is that when I use Double Click row event i cant call `afterSaveCell` Event and When I use `afterSaveCell` Event Dosen`t Update my data.
I want Both.so What's Solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote you before in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13285794/315935) on your previous answer that you can't mix inline editing with cell editing. The callback `afterSaveCell` will be called **only if you use cell editing**. So you should use `aftersavefunc` callback of [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) to recalculate contain of the `totalAmount` column based on new value from two other columns. For example if you have columns `amount` and `quantity` and need recalculate `totalAmount` based on the new values from the columns you can do the following:

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid,name,val,iRow,iCol) {
    $(this).jqGrid("editRow", rowid, {
        keys: true,
        aftersavefunc: function (rowid) {
            $(this).jqGrid("setCell", rowid, "totalAmount",
                parseFloat($(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "amount")) *
                parseFloat($(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "quantity")));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Oleg 
My Solution

```
$("#list").jqgrid(){
    ....
    editurl:"editMedicineGridData.html",
    onCellSelect : function(rowid, iCol, cellcontent) {
        $('#prescribedDate').val(jQuery("#madicineGrid").jqGrid('getCell',rowid, 'PrescriptionDate'));
    },
    gridComplete: function(){ 
        var grid = $("#madicineGrid"),
            sum = grid.jqGrid('getCol','totalAmount', false, 'sum');
        $('#totalMedicineCharge').html(sum);
    },
    beforeSubmitCell : function(rowid,celname,value,iRow,iCol)
    {
     if(celname=='SaleQuantity'){
return {'SaleQuantity':value,'id':rowid,'oper':'edit','Amount':jQuery("#madicineGrid").jqGrid('getCell',rowid,'Amount')};   
}},
afterSaveCell : function(rowid,name,val,iRow,iCol) {
        if(name == 'SaleQuantity') {
            var Qval = jQuery("#madicineGrid").jqGrid('getCell',rowid,'SaleQuantity');
            var Aval = jQuery("#madicineGrid").jqGrid('getCell',rowid,'Amount');
            jQuery("#madicineGrid").jqGrid('setRowData',rowid,{totalAmount: parseFloat(Aval) * parseFloat(Qval)});
        }
        var grid = $("#madicineGrid"),
            sum = grid.jqGrid('getCol','totalAmount', false, 'sum');
       $('#totalMedicineCharge').html(sum);
    } 
});
```