# how to set edit form position and size in jqgrid combining with other properties

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-ui-dialog

How to create jqgrid edit form at specified position and size which can changed in runtime?
Edit window postition should combined with other edit parameters in navGrid.

I tried code below but alert box does not appear and edit form is shown in default position.

```
var oldJqDnRstop,
  editWindowParams = { 
          left: 10,
          width: window.innerWidth-18,
          top: 5,
          height: 100
          };

if ($.jqDnR) {
    oldJqDnRstop = $.jqDnR.stop; // save original function
    $.jqDnR.stop = function (e) {
        var $dialog = $(e.target).parent(), dialogId = $dialog.attr("id"), position;
        oldJqDnRstop.call(this, e); // call original function
        if (typeof dialogId !== "string") {
            return;
        }
        if (dialogId.substr(0, 11) === "editmodgrid") {
            editWindowParams.width = $dialog.width();
            position = $dialog.position();
            editWindowParams.left = position.left;
            editWindowParams.top = position.top;
        }
    };
}


        $.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
          closeAfterAdd: true,
          recreateForm: true,
          reloadAfterSubmit: false,
          left: 10,
          dataheight: '100%',
          width: window.innerWidth-18
        });



     $grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#grid_toppager", { edit: true }, 
      { 
       top: function() { alert(editWindowParams.top); return editWindowParams.top; },
       left: function() { return editWindowParams.left; },
       width: function() { return editWindowParams.width; },
       height: function() { return editWindowParams.height; },

            afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) { 
              if (response.responseText.charAt(0) === '{') {
                var json = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                return [true, '', json.Id];
                }
              alert( decodeErrorMessage(response.responseText, '', ''));
              return [false, decodeErrorMessage(response.responseText, '', ''), null];
              },

            beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
              $("#tr_Info>td:eq(1)").attr("colspan", "2"); 
              $("#tr_Info>td:eq(1)>textarea").css("width", "95%"); 
              $("#tr_Info>td:eq(0)").hide(); 
              $("#tr_Markused>td:eq(1)").attr("colspan", "2"); 
              $("#tr_Markused>td:eq(1)>textarea").css("width", "95%"); 
              $("#tr_Markused>td:eq(0)").hide(); 
              beforeShowForm_base($form);
              },


            url: '/Edit',
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            onClose: function(){ 
              $( ".ui-autocomplete-input").trigger("blur");
            } 

       } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SaveEditDialogWidthWithPosition.htm) demonstrate the fixed code. It's modification of the demo from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13663106/315935). It uses the following code:

```
if ($.jqDnR) {
    oldJqDnRstop = $.jqDnR.stop; // save original function
    $.jqDnR.stop = function (e) {
        var $dialog = $(e.target).parent(), dialogId = $dialog.attr("id"),
            position, $form;

        oldJqDnRstop.call(this, e); // call original function
        if (typeof dialogId === "string") {
            if (dialogId.substr(0,14) === "searchmodfbox_") {
                // save the dialog position here
                searchParams.width = $dialog.width();
                position = $dialog.position();
                searchParams.left = Math.max(0, position.left);
                searchParams.top = Math.max(0, position.top);
            } else if (dialogId.substr(0,7) === "editmod") {
                // Add or Edit form
                editParams.width = $dialog.width();
                position = $dialog.position();
                editParams.left = Math.max(0, position.left);
                editParams.top = Math.max(0, position.top);
                $form = $dialog.find("form.FormGrid");
                if ($form.length > 0) {
                    editParams.dataheight = $form.height();
                }
                editParams.height = $dialog.height();
            } else if (dialogId.substr(0,6) === "delmod") {
                // Delete form
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. In question edit parameters passed to navGrid contains also other properties like afterSubmit etc. which contains parameters from MVC view. How to force usage of editParams values if edit form is created ?

Comment: @Andrus: You are welcome! Sorry, but I don't understand your question. One thing is clear for me that you use some parameters, like `top` for example, in wrong way as function. What you need to do is just define the edit parameters of `navGrid` as object `editWindowParams`. You should use the object `editWindowParams` as parameter of navGrid: `.jqGrid("navGrid", {}, editWindowParams, ...);`. In the case `editWindowParams` can have any methods too: `var editWindowParams = {top: 10, afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {...}, ...};`. All is really very simple.

Comment: demo referenced from answer does not use code from answer. There is no `Math.max` etc. usage in demo source code