# jqgrid returning back to the same grid page.

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqGrid with c# MVC

I have a scenerio where I click on a record and then need to open up a web page where the user can modify the information for that record. I am passing the page # to that page.

My question is when I am done with that page, I like to return back to the grid on the same page that I was on before.

Is there an example of how I can pass the page # to a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most easy way to implement the requirements would be just by implementing of saving of the state of the grid in the `localStorage` of web browser. I posted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935) and then some other answers with extension of the same idea (you can use for example [the query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:315935%20localStorage) to see the answers).

Comment: Hi Oleg, localStorage may be not ideal for us as some of our users may not be using the latest browser

Comment: @NatePet: What is "the latest browser"? It's perfectly supported on IE8. If you use [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) then you can use it in the same way on IE6/IE7 too but with the size of storage: 128 kB instead of 5 MB. If you need to save it on the server side you can modify the solution using Ajax call.