# jqGrid back button support

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, back, browser-history

I have a jqGrid that's filled with data rows when the user presses the 'search' button on demand. The grid contains href links that direct the users to visit another page upon clicking. When the user presses the 'back' button from the other page, the data in the grid is gone. Is there a way to preserve the previous data on the grid when the user visits back to my search result grid?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should save the grid details in localstorage. Please refer the following question which is similar to your case.

[Persisting jqGrid column preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422878/persisting-jqgrid-column-preferences)