Razor page issue .net 8
This is a Razor page issue. I have simple text box and corresponding search button created in the razor page, say it as index.cshtml.
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Search Button Example</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Disable the button initially
            $('#searchButton').prop('disabled', true);
 
            // Enable button if text box has value
            $('#searchInput').on('input', function () {
                const inputValue = $(this).val();
                if (inputValue.trim() !== "") {
                    $('#searchButton').prop('disabled', false);
                } else {
                    $('#searchButton').prop('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

and simple onGet method , which contains nothing.
The issue is: the search button is only enabled when user enters the text, which is working fine. But when the user press forward or back button of browser and reach to same page, button got disabled again, although it contains the data in the text box.
How can I resolve this?

Listening to pageshow, popstate, visibilitychange, and onpageshow events can solve the problem that the browser may not execute JavaScript code when returning to the previous page.
Here is my working sample.
Index.cshtml
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Search Button Example</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Define checkInput in the global scope
        function checkInput() {
            const inputValue = $('#searchInput').val();
            if (inputValue.trim() !== "") {
                $('#searchButton').prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                $('#searchButton').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Bind the input event
            $('#searchInput').on('input', checkInput);

            // Initial check on page load
            checkInput();
        });

        // pageshow event with event.persisted
        $(window).on('pageshow', function (event) {
            console.log('pageshow event fired');
            if (event.persisted) {
                console.log('Page was restored from bfcache');
            }
            checkInput();
        });

        // popstate event
        $(window).on('popstate', function (event) {
            console.log('popstate event fired');
            checkInput();
        });

        // visibilitychange event
        document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {
            if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
                console.log('visibilitychange event fired');
                checkInput();
            }
        });

        // window.onpageshow event
        window.onpageshow = function (event) {
            console.log('onpageshow event fired');
            checkInput();
        };
    </script>


</head>

<body>
    <form method="get">
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" name="searchQuery" value="@Model.SearchQuery" />
        <button type="submit" id="searchButton" disabled>Search</button>
    </form>
</body>

Index.cshtml.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication4.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        public string SearchQuery { get; set; }

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            SearchQuery = Request.Query["searchQuery"];
        }
    }
}


Hi it works , but have another issue ,  i fetch the data through ajax call and store and display to the user through jqgrid . it works fine , but again if the user click back or forward button of the browser and reach it to the same page  , feteched data is gone

Hi @rahulsingh， could you share your detailed code, so that we can investigate the issue deeper, if you think this is another issue, you also can post a new thread, thanks for your understanding.

no it is the part of the issue , i will share my exact code

https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79065627 @Jason Pan

i have started the another thread

Hi @rahulsingh The new thread was closed by community with Duplicate reason. Could you kindly check the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100911/jqgrid-back-button-support
