# Free jqGrid 4.8.0 - Saving and restoring Grid toolbarfilter, gridSearch (advanced search) and sorting orderFree

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I would like to be able to re-create the grid couple of times on the same table element.  I'm aware for the UnloadGrid example, but would like the filtering, sorting and advanced filtering to carry over the the "new" grid.

Since this is not supported with GridUnload, I am looking for a way to store temporarily all those variables and restore them once the new Grid is created.

Thanks,

Tal.

Comment: Do you know [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935). I think that you can modify the solution to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, is the "save and load" grid state: $("#savestate").click(function(){
   $.jgrid.saveState("jqGrid");
  });
  $("#loadstate").click(function(){
   $.jgrid.loadState("jqGrid");
  })  Will be supported in Free jqGrid?

Comment: The method `saveState` exist **after 4.7**. So one can't use the code directly because of new licence agreement. I plan to implement later saving of jqGrid stata, but I will define **the state** in another way as Tony implemented in `saveState` and `jqGridExport`.