# How to hide table columns using checkboxs and save preference with jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies, html-table

Given the below `HTML` table, I would like to hide columns when their checkboxes are un-checked and show them when the boxes are checked then save the preference of hiding or showing the columns so that when the page reloads, the columns are shown or hidden based on the preference.

How can I do this using `jQuery`?  Do I need to use `cookies`?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="opt1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="opt2" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="opt3" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="opt4" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="opt5" />
        </td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>column 1</td>
            <td>column 2</td>
            <td>column 3</td>
            <td>column 4</td>
            <td>column 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>column 1</td>
            <td>column 2</td>
            <td>column 3</td>
            <td>column 4</td>
            <td>column 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>column 1</td>
            <td>column 2</td>
            <td>column 3</td>
            <td>column 4</td>
            <td>column 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>column 1</td>
            <td>column 2</td>
            <td>column 3</td>
            <td>column 4</td>
            <td>column 5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: read [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422878/persisting-jqgrid-column-preferences) like you. full description.

Comment: now that your question has been reopened, you can mark it as answered : )

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO, you should really show what you have attempted so far on your own when asking questions. See--> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

That said, the below will do what you need using [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html):

**jQuery:**

```
// "data-control-column" is a custom data attrubute added to the html checkboxes
// when a check box changes loop through all, for any that are unchecked, add that checkbox's "data-control-column" value to our array
$('.opt').change(function(){ 
    var states = [];
    $('.opt').each(function(){
           if(!$(this).is(':checked')) states.push($(this).data('control-column'));         
    });
    setSates(states);
});

// when we need to set the sate of the UI, loop through the checkboxes checking if their "data-control-column" are in the "states" array 
// if so, hide the specified column and uncheck the box
function setSates(states){
     if(states){
         if(!$.isArray( states )) states = JSON.parse(states); // if sates came from localstorage it will be a string, convert it to an array
         $('.opt').each(function(i,e){ 
             var column =$(this).data('control-column');
             if($.inArray( column, states ) == -1){
                 $(this).attr('checked', true);
                 $('#myTable td:nth-child('+column+'), #myTable th:nth-child('+column+')').show(); 
             }
             else{
                 $(this).attr('checked', false);
                 $('#myTable td:nth-child('+column+'), #myTable th:nth-child('+column+')').hide(); 
             }
         });
         localStorage.setItem('states', JSON.stringify(states));
     }
}
// this will read and set the initial states when the page loads
setSates( localStorage.getItem('states') );
```

**html:**

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-control-column="1" class="opt" /> option one  
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-control-column="2" class="opt" /> option two 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-control-column="3" class="opt" /> option three 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-control-column="4" class="opt" /> option four 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-control-column="5" class="opt" /> option five 
        </td>
        </tr>
</table> 
<br><br>
<table border="1" id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td>column 1</td>
            <td>column 2</td>
            <td>column 3</td>
            <td>column 4</td>
            <td>column 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>column 1</td>
            <td>column 2</td>
            <td>column 3</td>
            <td>column 4</td>
            <td>column 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>column 1</td>
            <td>column 2</td>
            <td>column 3</td>
            <td>column 4</td>
            <td>column 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>column 1</td>
            <td>column 2</td>
            <td>column 3</td>
            <td>column 4</td>
            <td>column 5</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

### Here's a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/xvvbyLtm/4/)

Comment: Thanks guys
it goes like this
checkbox   checkbox     checkbox   checkbox
TableCol1    TableCol2  TableCol3  TableCol4
TableCol1    TableCol2  TableCol3  TableCol4
TableCol1    TableCol2  TableCol3  TableCol4
....             ...             ....            ....  

if i unchecked the checkbox above it will hide the column below it then save preference. And when page reload it will show the preference done.example  If unchecked col1 col3 it will hide the table column and when i reload, it will keep that preference

Comment: Are you saying that you want a checkbox to show or hide each column?

Comment: im able to do the hide show but not able to do the save preference thing

here is what i have

$(document).on('change', 'table thead input', function() {
 
 
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");

 localStorage.setItem('state', 'true');
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
 
        $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
   
            if(checked) {
    
    
    
    $(this).find("td").eq(index).show();   
    
                
            } else {
    
    
    $(this).find("td").eq(index).hide();  
   
    
               
            }
   
   
    
   
        });
  
  
});

Comment: I'll be off work in a bit and I'll update the above : )

Comment: <table><thead><td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="opt1" /></td><td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="opt2"/></td><td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="opt3"/></td><td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="opt4"/></td><td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="opt5"/></td></thead><tbody><tr><td>column 1</td><td>column 2</td><td>column 3</td><td>column 4</td> <td>column 5</td></tr>

Comment: <tr><td>column 1</td><td>column 2</td><td>column 3</td><td>column 4</td> <td>column 5</td></tr><tr><td>column 1</td><td>column 2</td><td>column 3</td><td>column 4</td><td>column 5</td></tr><tr><td>column 1</td><td>column 2</td><td>column 3</td><td>column 4</td><td>column 5</td></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: No problem. I updated, my answer above. However, you will not be able to have the checkboxes in the table like you show. If you did that, when you hide the column, it would also hide the checkbox leaving you with no way to show the column again. My example avoids this by putting the boxes in a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some columns that are unchecked by default. These Columns will not be hidden for visitors who have never been to the page before, even though they are are in a unchecked state.

As 'states' will be null, and the setStates function will never run.

This modified version of DelightedD0D's answer should fix.

```
  // "data-control-column" is a custom data attrubute added to the html checkboxes
    // when a check box changes loop through all, for any that are unchecked, add that checkbox's "data-control-column" value to our array

    //  localStorage.clear(); uncomment this line to clear local storage.
    var states = [];

    $('.opt').change(function() {
        states = [];
        $('.opt').each(function() {
            if (!$(this).is(':checked')) states.push($(this).data('control-column'));
        });
        setSates(states);       
    });
    // when we need to set the sate of the UI, loop through the checkboxes checking if their "data-control-column" are in the "states" array 
    // if so, hide the specified column and uncheck the box
    function setSates(states) {
        if (states) {
            if (!$.isArray(states)) states = JSON.parse(states); // if sates came from localstorage it will be a string, convert it to an array
            $('.opt').each(function(i, e) {
                var column = $(this).data('control-column');
                if ($.inArray(column, states) == -1) {
                    $(this).attr('checked', true);
                    $('#myTable td:nth-child(' + column + '), #myTable th:nth-child(' + column + ')').show();
                } else {
                    $(this).attr('checked', false);
                    $('#myTable td:nth-child(' + column + '), #myTable th:nth-child(' + column + ')').hide();
                }
            });
            localStorage.setItem('states', JSON.stringify(states));
        } else {        
            states = [];
            $('.opt').each(function() {
                if (!$(this).is(':checked')) states.push($(this).data('control-column'));
            });
            setSates(states);
        }
    }
    // this will read and set the initial states when the page loads
    setSates(localStorage.getItem('states'));
```