# How can I preserve the page number and sort criteria in jqGrid on page reload?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

What is the best practise of using jqgrid to preserve the page number and sort criteria in jqGrid on page reload ? Should I store these values into the cookie or there are some other best practise to achive this behaviour with jqgrid ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8547852/315935) show how use `localStorage` of web browser to save some user preferences inclusive page number and sort criteria and how to restore the information on the reloading of the page. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3044974/315935) shows how to use cookies to save the information. I prefer personally `localStorage` and described the reason of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935).