# Problem passing a JSON object to a function

Tags: javascript, json

I'm only just learning javascript so I imagine this is relatively simple but it's been annoying me for a while now.

I have a function that simply displays some text that I am calling from a AJAX response. Here's my code.

```
if(this.responseText != null)
{
    var text = "<ul>";
    var object = eval("(" + this.responseText + ")");
    var track;
    for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++)
    {
        track = object[i];
        text += "<li><img src=\"" + track.artwork_url + "\"/>";
        text += track.title;
        text += "<ul><li><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"playTrack(" + track + ");return false;\">Play</a></li>"
        text += "<li><a href=\"" + track.download_url + "?client_id=" + clientId + "\">Download</a></li></ul>"

        text += "</li>";
    }


    text += "</ul>";

    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = text;
}

function playTrack(track)
{
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "This has worked";
}
```

It's not liking me passing the track object to the function playTrack (a simple function for now that just displays some text). I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

If I pass in track.id (or any other property), it all works fine which I don't understand.

Thanks for any help,

Mister B.

Comment: You shouldn't use `eval()` on JSON strings. Instead you should use a JSON parser. Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891299/browser-native-json-support-window-json for native JSON support. If it's not supported on all the browsers you want to target, then use a JavaScript based JSON parser: http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass an object like this.  `track` is getting converted to a string and then your `playTrack` function call fails because the syntax is wrong.  It'll be rendered (something like `onclick=playTrack([Object object])` which clearly isn't valid JavaScript).  What's wrong with just passing the track.id since you know that works?

Comment: I need to access about 4 or 5 other properties of the `track` object in the `playTrack` function. I thought (coming from a c# background it makes sense to me) that I could pass the `track` object in rather than individual properties.

Comment: You can still pass the track's ID to your playTrack and then look up the real track object in a dictionary keyed on ID.  You cannot (obviously) "pass" an object through a String and expect to to be an object again later on. :)

Comment: I'm quite confused by this and I appreciate I may seem a little dense. If I can access `track.id` as a property of the `track` object, then surely `track` is the object itself no? How come `track` is a string if it has properties?

Thanks for taking the time to respond to my stupidity :-)

Comment: Right, I think I'm understanding this now. It's because of the context I'm using it it's getting converted to a string. For the other uses of the properties, this is fine but in the instance of the object itself, I can see how this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The @alpian and @Jim is right, you need convert the object to json string, you can use http://www.json.org/js.html to this.

```
...    
text += "<ul><li><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"playTrack('" + JSON.stringify(track) + "');return false;\">Play</a></li>"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating the "playTrack" onclick event, you are using the track variable in the wrong way. "track" is an object, and using it as a string will be [Object object]. So in your "html" you'll have something like onclick="playtrack([Object object])" and this is syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest the use of `JSON.parse()` instead of `eval`. Instead of building your list entries as text I'd make them as DOM objects with `document.createElement()` and add the click handlers as `addEventListener`, that way you wouldn't have the need to try to include your JS objects as text in the HTML stream.

Comment: I'm new to javascript and interested in your approach to this, can you give me more of an indication as how I would do it this way...?