# javascript, curly brace in onclick dont work?

Tags: javascript, curly-braces

Solved, server side ate my {}.

I have this code in my HTML:

```
onclick="changes = {'a': 'b'};"
```

This transforms to

```
onclick="changes = ;"
```

when I load the page. So the curly braces and everything in between disappears. Any idea how to fix this? Ultimately, I want to give an anonymous object as input to a function:

```
onclick="dothis({'a': 'b', '1': '2'});"
```

Comment: Do you mean the server strips them out before sending to browser? What are you using server-side?

Comment: I just gave this a quick try in FF and IE9. For me the onclick stays as I wrote it:
<h2 onclick="changes = {'a': 'b'};">New</h2>

Comment: Don't think so but will check it out.

Comment: Created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvKa6/). Works fine for me on Chrome. But you should accept the advice from @Eli and not rely on inline event handlers.

Comment: Yes, it's server side. Sorry.

Comment: Please either delete this question or write an answer to it yourself and accept that one.

Answer (score 4):

What I would recommend is making your code more semantic, by having your inputs keep track of data, but the actual binding and execution separate:

```
<div id="myDiv" data-changes="{'a':'b', '1':'2'}"></div>


document.getElementById('myDiv').onclick = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.getAttribute('data-changes'));

    // here you should be able to say data.a, data.1, etc.
};
```

Most modern browsers support native JSON methods:

[Browser-native JSON support (window.JSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891299/browser-native-json-support-window-json)

but for those that don't, you can add support with the JSON library:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered/are you able to not use inline JavaScript? Just have an external JavaScript file that gets loaded with something like (not actual code, for example purposes):

```
getElementById("myButton").click( function(){
   dothis({'a':'b','1':'2'})
})
```

Something like that (especially when paired with a library) can also save you from having to duplicate your code in every item you're looking to run that function in.

Comment: Please take into account that the example given is pseudo-code, not something that actually works.