# What is the best way to make a JSON object in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

What is the best way to make a JSON object in jQuery (without using a parser or AJAX)?

```
var JSONobj = new JSON({'a':'b'})
```

Comment: [From ECMAScript 5th](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.12): *"The JSON object does not have a [[Construct]] internal property; it is not possible to use the JSON object as a constructor with the new operator."*

Answer (score 6):

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a
>   lightweight data-interchange format.
>   It is easy for humans to read and
>   write. It is easy for machines to
>   parse and generate. It is based on a
>   subset of the JavaScript Programming
>   Language, Standard ECMA-262 3rd
>   Edition - December 1999. JSON is a
>   text format that is completely
>   language independent but uses
>   conventions that are familiar to
>   programmers of the C-family of
>   languages...These properties make JSON an
>   ideal data-interchange language.

[source](http://www.json.org/)

JSON is a subset of the object literal notation of JavaScript. Since JSON is a subset of JavaScript, it can be used in the language with no muss or fuss.

```
var myJSONObject = {"bindings": [
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "deleteURI", "regex": "^delete.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "randomURI", "regex": "^random.*"}
    ]
};
```

[source](http://www.json.org/js.html)

However to parse JSON from an external source or serialize JSON objects from your own code, you'll need a library such as [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) as Javascript/ECMAScript doesn't currently support this, although:

> It is expected that native JSON
>   support will be included in the next
>   ECMAScript standard.

Comment: ECMAScript 5th ed. supports JSON natively. See section [15.12](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) - JSON Object.

Answer (score 4):

JSON is the serialized representation of an object. It is just a string. To create a JSON representation out of a JavaScript object, use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```
var myObject = { hello: "world", foo: [ "bar", "baz", 42 ] };

JSON.stringify(myObject); // "{"hello":"world","foo":["bar","baz",42]}"
```

Comment: Be aware that not all browsers support JSON.stringify.

Comment: @Greg - most modern browsers do [support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891299/browser-native-json-support-window-json) it natively, and for the ones that don't, easy to [add](https://gist.github.com/443002) it yourselves.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just use an object literal syntax:

```
var JSONobj = {'a':'b'};
```

Comment: I think he really wants a JSON serialization of an existing JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you just want to create an object, create it...

```
var myObj = { a : "b" };
```

Comment: In your example you created a javascript object but it is not a JSON.