# Extracting values with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a variable called "result",

```
var result;
```

that result value is equal to following value, please presume that is just a string :)

---------result value -----------

```
for (;;);{
     "send":1,
     "payload":{
         "config":{
             "website":"",
             "title":"welcome to site",
             "website-module":1313508674538,
             "manufatureid":"id.249530475080015",
             "tableid":"id.272772962740259",
             "adminid":100002741928612,
             "offline":null,
             "adminemail":"admin@website.com",
             "adminame":"George",
             "tags":"web:design:template",
             "source":"source:design:web",
             "sitelog":[],
             "errorlog":0,
             "RespondActionlog":0,
             "map":null
           },
        "imgupload":""
     },
     "criticalerror":[0],
     "report":true
 }
```

---------result value------------

From that value, I would like to extract tableid which is "id.272772962740259" with classic Javascript.

How can I extract the code, please let me know how can i do with simple javascript, please don't use Jquery, all I just need is simple javascript.

Comment: Is it JSON or string? Why the empty for loop in front?

Comment: Is "result" a string containing that code? And are you using jQuery or any other library? Could make this a lot easier...

Comment: result value is respond from Ajax respond. All I just need is to extract the value of tableid and assign to another variable.

Comment: please, presume that the result is a string. we can't remove "for (;;);"

Answer (score 2):

You can simply evaluate the value of the variable to obtain the values. However, please note that your current value is not valid JSON; that `for(;;);` at the beginning of the value invalidates the format. Remove that, and you can do this:

```
var object = eval('(' + resultMinusThatForLoop + ')');

alert(object.payload.config.tableid);
```

Comment: Just got there before me. It's worth noting that future versions of ECMAScript may contain a JSON parser however right now, eval seems to be the best solution (other than using a JSON parse in a framework).

Answer (score 1):

If that data is a string the parse it with a JSON parse. The following should get the value you want

```
JSON.parse(result).payload.config.tableid; // "id.272772962740259"
```

Edit: though, as Tejs says, the `for(;;)` invalidates the string and stops it from being parsed. If you can remove that, do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the empty `for` loop, then parse the string. DO NOT use `eval`; most modern browsers provide built-in JSON-parsing facilities, but you can use [`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) if yours does not. Assuming that you assign the results of parsing the JSON to `result`, you should be able to get that value using `result.payload.config.tableid`.

You should probably read a good JS reference. [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) or [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) would be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

If result is a javascript object and not a string, you can just use 'result.payload.config.tableid'.

If it is not, how do you get the AJAX result?  Are you using XmlHttpRequest directly?  Most libraries will give you a javascript object, you might be missing a flag or not sending the response back with the right content type.

If it is a string and you want to parse it manually, you should use a JSON parser.  Newer browsers have one built in as [window.JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891299/browser-native-json-support-window-json), but there is [open source code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) for parsing it as well.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(result);
alert('tableid is ' + obj.payload.config.tableid);
```

Comment: i am using XmlHttpRequest in order to get that result.