# JavaScript push to array object is not working

Tags: javascript, json

I have an html like below

HTML:

```
 <INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="clcik" onClick="add('1234','blah')" />
 <input type="hidden" id="project" value="" />
```

JS:

```
    function add(obj1 , obj2){
    var jsonArray = [];
    var jsonObj = { product_id : obj1 , name : obj2 };
    jsonArray.push(jsonObj);
    var field = document.getElementById('project');
    field.setAttribute('value', JSON.stringify(jsonArray));
    alert(field.getAttribute('value'));
    }
```

I am trying to set first and retrieve again to check but nothing is happening..I can't understand where I am wrong...?

Comment: Where is the stringData variable set?

Comment: @jfriend00, I'm sure that's it.  Write up an answer with `var stringData = JSON.stringify(jsonArray)` replaced.

Comment: Its probably the output of `JSON.stringify`

Comment: This is not jQuery related - i've removed the tag and updated the title.

Comment: Your question are all about one and the same problem. You won't get far if you are trying to solve the problem step by step by asking questions here (and questions about solutions you get here). I really recommend you to take a step back and read about JavaScript, DOM, HTML etc so that you have a basic understanding of it and can use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you missed to get the stringify result into `stringData` variable because of which you are getting a js error before it reaches the line where you are trying to alert the value.

`JSON` or `JSON.stringify` is not provided by `jQuery` you have to include [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) library on the page if the browser natively do not support it.

Try this

```
function add(obj1 , obj2){
    var jsonArray = [];
    var jsonObj = { product_id : obj1 , name : obj2 };

    jsonArray.push(jsonObj);
    var stringData = JSON.stringify(jsonArray);

    var field = document.getElementById('project');

    field.setAttribute('value', stringData);
    alert(field.getAttribute('value'));
}
```

Code to remove element from array based on your request in the comment.

```
var newArray = [], productIdToRemove = "1234";
$.each(jsonArray, function(){
   if(this.product_id != productIdToRemove){
      newArray.push(this);
   }
});

//Now newArray will not have '1234'
```

Comment: `JSON` or `JSON.stringify` is not provided by `jQuery` you have to include json2 library on the page.

Comment: @Shankar most browsers will actually include JSON natively. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891299/browser-native-json-support-window-json/891306#891306

Comment: I think < IE8  do not have it natively

Comment: @User - You had a js error in your fiddle, take a look at this fiddle it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/qWCwa/8/

Comment: You were not checking for empty value for the first time. Try this fiddle I fixed it http://jsfiddle.net/qWCwa/16/

Comment: i want something like when during push I want to check if something with same product_id is already present then don't push. Else push it.

Comment: well one last request what should i do if i want some product id to be deleted from the hidden field value.

Comment: Loop through the array and keep pushing the elements which do not match product id into a new array, at the end of the loop you will have a new array which do not have the matching product id.

Comment: if you are satisfied with my answer please mark it as an answer, thanks.

Comment: well how can i delete  {"product_id":"1234","name":"blah"} from this [{"product_id":"1234","name":"blah"},{"product_id":"1235","name":"blah"}] so as to get the resulting value as [{"product_id":"1235","name":"blah"}],,,

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
JSON.stringify(jsonArray)
// to
var stringData = JSON.stringify(jsonArray);
```

---

Other problems with the fiddle, fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/qWCwa/7/

Comment: Open your browser's console and you will have a world of useful information at your fingertips. Namely: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` because there is an extra semicolon in the `setAttribute()` method call.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you never set `stringData`.

Answer (score 0):

get/set the "value" property directly on the input, not getAttribute and setAttribute methods.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the code to assign stringData, it seems to work for me:

```
function add(obj1 , obj2){
    var jsonArray = [];
    var jsonObj = { product_id : obj1 , name : obj2 };
    jsonArray.push(jsonObj);
    var stringData = JSON.stringify(jsonArray)
    var field = document.getElementById('project');
    field.setAttribute('value', stringData);
    alert(field.getAttribute('value'));
    }

add(1, 2);
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/HNuak/.

FYI, if you just run in an environment where you can see javascript execution errors (like the Chrome or Firefox debuggers), errors like this would be easy to see in the error console.

Comment: Your jsFiddle settings were such that the add() function definition was not in the global scope so the checkbox code couldn't find it.  I changed the jsFiddle settings and now it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/YL8eU/.  Once again, you just need to use a JS debugger so you can see the JS errors and you would know how to see the cause of these issues in seconds.