# Which browsers natively support the JSON object?

Tags: json, browser-support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Browser-native JSON support (window.JSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891299/browser-native-json-support-window-json)

Recent browsers such as Chrome, and Firefox all have native implementations of the json.js JSON object. However what about Opera, Safari, Safri, Mobile, Android Stock, Android Dolphin, and the various versions of IE?

I've been looking online to find a support chart and for the life of me I can't. I'm writing a tutorial demo and really need json serialization only for the demo itself, I'd really rather not include anything that is orthogonal to the feature itself.

Comment: Thanks @Jon - That definitely looks like a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, it was all webkit browsers, Firefox 3.5+, IE8+, and Opera 10.5+. Android and safari all use webkit.

Answer (score 0):

I can see most of the browsers listed are found in mobile devices(Unsupported ones).Most mobile browser don't support javascript 100% unless you do it in a good way.
Why don't you try sencha plattform.It is built using EXT JS. and they have tried to factor in the small browsers/new browser compatibility.

Comment: Because I'm not trying to demo sencha platform, or ext js, I'm trying to demo my own plugin and every dependency that I introduce on the demo page will be increasing the complexity for consumers. Think about it. When you look at a product demo - you just want to see what it takes to make it work, not a bunch of extra code that's unrelated.