# How to print this hash Table data in java script

Tags: javascript

How to print this hash Table data in java script

```
var product = {
    "prduct_name": "Mobile",
    "product_attribute": {
        "attribute_name": "Brand",
        "type": "combo",
        "product_attribute_values": {
            "attribute_value": "Apple",
            "brand_price": "2000"
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What doesn't work?  What is your target platform (web browser? jQuery? JScript? Node.js)?

Comment: I assume that the question must be more complicated than you're stating here.  After all, if your objective really was just to display a string (however arbitrary) doing so in HTML is trivial, and doing so in javascript (why would you not just do it in HTML?) only slightly less so.

Comment: how to print hash key and values with nested hash key with values??

Answer (score 11):

If your (or target) browser has the JSON object available (
 Internet Explorer 8+, Firefox 3.1+, Safari 4+, Chrome 3+, and Opera 10.5+
 [Browser-native JSON support (window.JSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891299/browser-native-json-support-window-json)
) then I suggest as a quick development sol.

`str = JSON.stringify(product);`

or if you want it all pretty like:

`str = JSON.stringify(product, null, "  ");`

This will probably not be appropriate for a client facing display however!

Comment: This will work but you must have JSON in the page which is not available on all browsers

Comment: Support is pretty good for JSON -> Internet Explorer 8+, Firefox 3.1+, Safari 4+, Chrome 3+, and Opera 10.5+

Comment: true, I guess sometimes with those questions poster should let us know what are they aiming to support.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, have updated the answer to show additional info

Answer (score 0):

Edited as didn't saw the nested object data.

http://jsfiddle.net/wYWQJ/

```
function printData(data) {
    var str = '';
    for (var key in data) {
        if (typeof data[key] == 'object') str += key + printData(data[key]) + ' ';
        else str += key + ' => ' + data[key] + ' ';
    }
    return str;
};

console.log(printData(product));
```

Comment: Don't forget wrapper characters around the outside of each key/product pair.  Currently, your version has product[n] and key[n+1] butting up against one another in a potentially indistinguishable way.

Comment: How to print all key  with values??