# Serialize/Unserialize javascript and be read by PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I know it is possible to serialize and unserialize in PHP and then have javascript read the response, my question is can I do it the other way around?  I have a function that may be called multiple times and each time it is called I need the new data added to an array or an object of some form.  Then I want to take all of this data and send it to PHP to be interpreted and analyzed as if it were an array.

I think I am drawing a blank here, and this should be easily done xD  Oh yeah and i am storing the information temporarily in a hidden field until it is ready for submission (I will be doing security checks in PHP as well)

Thanks :D

Comment: Google json_encode and json_decode in php.  Should be what you're looking for.  :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make JavaScript serialize in the syntax of PHP's serialize would require a custom JavaScript function, however you can do what you want with JSON.

To serialize to JSON in JavaScript you would use the stringify method of the [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON):

```
JSON.stringify(myArray)
```

and to unserialize a JSON string in PHP you would use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php%20%22json_decode):

```
json_decode($myJsonArray)
```

If you want to support older browsers, you will have to include an external implementation of the JSON object. See [Browser-native JSON support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891299/browser-native-json-support-window-json)

Answer (score 0):

encode the data with JavaScript into JSON and then post it urlencoded to the server. On the server use json_decode to parse the array.

Comment: An example could improve your answer. So could a link to the docs for JSON encoding in JS, urlencoding, and `json_decode()`.