# How to parse a json string alert

Tags: javascript, html, json

Hi how i can parse this json string: `{"Error":true, "data":["not available","somethinghere"]}`

but that string i get it from an alert like this:

`alert(ff.Result.value);`

i need to get from that alert just the "not available" from the json string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most modern browsers support the JSON object:

```
var errorObject = JSON.parse(ff.Result.value);
alert(errorObject.data[0]);
```

See [Browser-native JSON support (window.JSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891299/browser-native-json-support-window-json)

An example using json2.js:

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js"></script>
<script>
    var errorObject = JSON.parse(ff.Result.value);
    document.getElementById('someId').innerHTML += errorObject.data[0];
</script>
```

Comment: software uses ie6 :( too bad but thats the true

Comment: Then use one of the libraries from json.org as a fallback, for example https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: its a string i need to get the json from alert(ff.AsPosResult.value); that value then parse it to get  just "not available"

Comment: i need to get from that alert just the "not available" from the json string

Comment: and how i can do it native without json2? theres a way to do that?

Comment: you can eval('var errorObject = ' + ff.Result.value); but that might bring all sorts of problems... it will just crash if the JSON is invalid

Comment: Why don't you use json2? You can not include third party js?

Comment: no i cant really your method works perfect but i cannot use it

Comment: And eval? What do you mean "maybe without array?"

Comment: maybe with an array or something sorry :)

Comment: aaand why don't you use eval?)

Comment: var res = eval("(" + Result.value + ")");
  alert(res.data[0]);

Comment: one more thing bro im trying to write the res.data result to a div named: acc_inputs i wrote like u said document.getElementById('acc_inputs').innerHTML += res.data[0]; but doesnt works

Comment: What does it say? The div must be like this: <div id="acc_inputs">123</div>. name="acc_inputs" does not count