# PHP read Javascript array

Tags: php, javascript

I am passing an array from Javascript to PHP page, as below.

```
var arrF1 = [{"Item":"item1no",
      "Desc":"item1desc",
      "Remarks":"item1note"},
             {"Item":"item2no",
      "Desc":"item2desc",
      "Remarks":"item2note"}
    ];
$.ajax({        
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://www.mydomain.com/pdfs/flist.php",
   data: { favArray : arrF1 },
   success: function() {
        alert('ok, sent');
   }
});
```

In my PHP page, I read the array as below.

```
$fArray = json_decode($_POST['favArray'])
```

And I tried to access the arrays value like this.

```
$fArrav[0]->{'Item'}
$fArrav[0]->{'Desc'}
$fArrav[1]->{'Item'}
```

Is this correct?
I am generating a PDF on the server using FPDF.
But with the above, its not reading the array.

I must not be doing this right.
Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `var_dump($fArray)` to make sure it's being populated properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this PHP:

```
function handlePost() {
    $a = $_POST['favArray'];
    var_dump($a);
}
```

..and this Javascript:

```
function post() {
    var a1 = [ 
        {"Item":"109249383",
         "Desc":"item1desc",
         "Remarks":"item1note"},

        {"Item":"298298210",
         "Desc":"item2desc",
         "Remarks":"item2note"}
    ];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "readArray.php",
        data: { favArray : a1 },
        success: function() {
            alert1('ok, sent');
        }
    });
}
```

...I get this output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10
Date: Wed, 11 Jul 2012 21:04:16 GMT
Content-Length: 315

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Item"]=>
    string(9) "109249383"
    ["Desc"]=>
    string(9) "item1desc"
    ["Remarks"]=>
    string(9) "item1note"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Item"]=>
    string(9) "298298210"
    ["Desc"]=>
    string(9) "item2desc"
    ["Remarks"]=>
    string(9) "item2note"
  }
}
```

In this case, the encoding of the data on the wire is **not JSON**.  It is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' as per the default used by jQuery's `ajax` function. Looks like this:

```
favArray=%5B%7B%22Item%22%3A%22109249383%22%2C%22Desc%22%3A%22item1desc%22%2C
    %22Remarks%22%3A%22item1note%22%7D%2C%7B%22Item%22%3A%22298298210%22%2C%22
    Desc%22%3A%22item2desc%22%2C%22Remarks%22%3A%22item2note%22%7D%5D
```

(all on one line)
Therefore it does not make sense to call `json_decode` within PHP - there was never any JSON involved. PHP decodes the url-encoded post body automatically.

---

If you *want* to encode with JSON, then you can use `JSON.stringify()` directly.  This *may* require `json2.js` on the browser side. (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891299/browser-native-json-support-window-json/891306#891306))

To use JSON, then you would need something like this in the browser:

```
function post_json_encoded() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "postArray.php",
        contentType: 'application/json', // outbound header
        dataType: 'text',                // expected response
        data: JSON.stringify(a1),        // explicitly encode
        success: function() {
            alert1('ok, json sent');
        }
    });
}
```

...and then something like this on the php side:

```
function handlePost() {
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"');
    $post_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $a = json_decode($post_body);
    var_dump($a);
}
```

In this case the on-the-wire representation looks like this:

```
[{"Item":"109249383","Desc":"item1desc","Remarks":"item1note"},
 {"Item":"298298210","Desc":"item2desc","Remarks":"item2note"}]
```

...and the php var_dump output is this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
    ["Item"]=>
    string(9) "109249383"
    ["Desc"]=>
    string(9) "item1desc"
    ["Remarks"]=>
    string(9) "item1note"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["Item"]=>
    string(9) "298298210"
    ["Desc"]=>
    string(9) "item2desc"
    ["Remarks"]=>
    string(9) "item2note"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the very detail explaination.  I was able to get this to work from studying what you'd said (I'm VERY new to this).  Ended up without the json decode, and type urlencoded.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$fArray = $_POST['favArray'];
echo $fArray[0]['Item']; // item1no
echo $fArray[1]['Item']; // item2no
```

Answer (score 0):

NO need for the extra brackets:

```
$fArrav[0]->Item
```