# Parsing JSON in jquery Yahoo Weather API

Tags: jquery, json

I cannot figure this out at all.

my current json results the following using `console.log(json)`

[Click to view Json Response](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid=%2726344339%27%20and%20u=%27c%27&format=json&callback=)

I was wondering if someone could help me retrieve the Condition part?

**EDIT**

```
                       var geoFORECAST = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid=%2726344339%27%20and%20u=%27c%27&format=json';
                    $.getJSON(geoFORECAST, function(json) {
                       console.log(json);
                       console.log(json.query.results.item.condition.text);
                     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [native JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON) object.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var condition = obj.query.results.channel.item.condition;
```

Comment: @Madbreaks yes, Its supported in [most modern browser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/891306/376535).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `parseJSON`:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Then just access the `Condition` var like you would any object property.

Answer (score 0):

Item is already parsed so save what that pages sends back to varible test and code below iwll work

and access things like..

```
test.query.results.item.condition.text
```

Which will return a value

To do conditions you could do

```
var b =  test.query.results.item.condition.text ;
```

`if(b == ???)` or even > or < or what ever is required

Comment: I just receive this. SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: Sorry its still not working.ReferenceError: test is not defined