# turn string into an array?

Tags: javascript, json

If I have this below as a string, how can I easily make that into an array?

```
"[[0.01,4.99,0.01],[5,14.95,0.05]]"
```

I want the same result as:

```
var x = [[0.01,4.99,0.01],[5,14.95,0.05]];
```

Answer (score 9):

```
var x = JSON.parse("[[0.01,4.99,0.01],[5,14.95,0.05]]");
```

Or the way jQuery does JSON parsing (better than `eval`):

```
var x = (new Function("return " + "[[0.01,4.99,0.01],[5,14.95,0.05]]"))();
```

To make this answer complete, you can use a polyfill for older browsers to support `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`. I recommend [json3](http://bestiejs.github.com/json3/), because Crockfords json2 is to crockfordy (insiders know what I mean).

Comment: Big up for the `function` version :)

Answer (score 5):

```
var x = JSON.parse("[[0.01,4.99,0.01],[5,14.95,0.05]]");
```

For older browsers that don't have the built-in JSON object you might want to download Crockford's [`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), which defines a JSON object with the same API if it's not already defined.

Comment: +1 for mentioning json2.js. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891299/browser-native-json-support-window-json

Comment: As a side note, you might be tempted to use eval() instead of JSON.parse for browsers that do not have JSON defined, but do NOT. Use Corckford's js to make it work.