# Parsing Nested Objects in a Json using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, loops

I have a Json in this format:

```
{"year":{"month1":{"date1":{"device1":{"users":6}}}}
```

Sample:

```
{"2013":{"2":{"5":{"GT-N7000":{"users":1}},"6":{"GT-N7000":{"users":9},"HTC Sensation Z710a":{"users":1}},"7":{"GT-N7000":{"users":15},"HTC Sensation Z710a":{"users":2},"M903":{"users":1}}}}}
```

How can I generate new arrays of users from the Json. For example:

```
GT-N7000 = [1, 9, 15]
M903 = [1]
```

I have tried nested `for` loop and I have tried `for..in` loop too. I am sure I am making a mistake. Any ideas how I can filter/parse the required information for such nested json objects?

Comment: Please post your code and we might be able to help you with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine you would do something like:

```
var json = {"2013":{"2":{"5":{"GT-N7000":{"users":1}},"6":{"GT-N7000":{"users":9},"HTC Sensation Z710a":{"users":1}},"7":{"GT-N7000":{"users":15},"HTC Sensation Z710a":{"users":2},"M903":{"users":1}}}}}; 

var result = {}, year, month, date, item;
for (year in json) {
  for(month in json[year]) {
    for(date in json[year][month]) {
       for(item in json[year][month][date]) {
          if(item in result) {
              result[item].push(json[year][month][date][item].users)  // this bit might need editing?
          } else {
              result[item] = [json[year][month][date][item].users] // this be also might need editing
          }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers support the native JSON.parse method.  See this question for details [Browser-native JSON support (window.JSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891299/browser-native-json-support-window-json)