# JavaScript / jQuery version of PHP's serialize() function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, serialization

I'm looking for the most up-to-date way to serialize an array of data in Javascript (w/ or w/o jQuery). Using the latest version of the Chrome browser (June 2013).

Simple associative array, PHP using serialize().

```
array('product_id' => "145549", "field" => "price")
```

-- serializes to --

```
a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:6:"145549";s:5:"field";s:5:"price";}
```

If there's no easy way to produce the same serialized string using Javascript, is there an equivalent to PHP's json_encode()?

Comment: use `phpjs`, you can use all php kind of function in javascript.

Comment: That PHP's serialisation format kinda looks a bit like JSON except a little bloated up. Stick to JSON

Comment: Serialization is for communication with different languages. AFAIK, PHP's serialization only allows communication with itself. It's highly recommend -- if you want to send data to javascript, to use JSON.

Comment: we'd be able to help more if you provided why/what you are trying to accomplish.  It's all about using the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Brombomb: I think I can rewrite my code to use json_encode() in PHP and JSON.stringify() in JavaScript. I was just hoping to avoid the rewrite of the serialize PHP code. BTW, the data is being sent from PHP or Javascript to a PHP backend method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on what Musa said in a comment. Most modern browsers supply a JSON object. You can use object detection to see if it is available. No jQuery required even if the browser does not have it you can supply it yourself, [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Native support: [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891299/browser-native-json-support-window-json), even has some nice code examples.