# How can I find out if an object has contents?

Tags: javascript

If I set a variable like this:

```
var a = {};
```

Check if it has any contents

```
var b = { x: 1 }
```

Check if it has any contents

```
var c = { y: null }
```

I think the test (a) will not work as it is not null. So how can I check if it has some contents if I do not know in advance what the contents are?  In this case I want variables `b` and `c` to show up as having contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a piece of code what jQuery does:

```
// ...
isEmptyObject: function( obj ) {
    var name;
    for ( name in obj ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
},
// ...
```

Comment: Should mention that [this doesn't work in old IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891299/browser-native-json-support-window-json) (not a concern for most, but worth noting)

Comment: Functions don't get stringified into JSON

Comment: @xdazz— `JSON.stringify({foo:function(){}}) == '{}'` returns `true`.

Comment: @RobG Oh, that's true.

Answer (score 1):

```
function isEmpty(input)
{
    var result = true;


    for(item in input)
        result = false;

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little wordy, but this should work:

```
var hasProperties = false;
for(var prop in obj) {
    hasProperties = true;
    break;
}
```

Comment: And for inhertied enumerable properties?

Comment: Inherited enumerable properties should be detected using this, which as I assume, is favorable behaviour for the OP. Though, according to the scenario of "if I set a variable like var a = {...}," inheritance should not be an issue.

Comment: I guess it highlights the futility of a general purpose "is plain object" test, they all only work within a limited set of criteria. In the above, extending *Object.prototype* with an enumerable properties means that all objects "have contents".

Answer (score 0):

Try `if(Object.keys(a).length)`.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers, but I guess you want to check for **own** properties of the object:

```
for (var p in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
    // obj has at least one enumerable own property
  }
}
```

But note that in ES5, objects can be constructed with non–enumerable own properties:

```
function hasEnumerableOwnProperties(obj) {
  for (var p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

var obj = {}

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo', {enumerable:false, value:'foo'})

console.log(hasEnumerableOwnProperties(obj) + ':' + obj.foo); // false:foo
```

Javascript isn't designed to suit this kind of analysis, it's much better if you're after a particular property, feature or attribute to test for it specifically (i.e. use feature detection).

Don't try to infer some general behaviour based on a simple (often inconclusive) test (duck typing).