# How do I create JSON in ExtJS for an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, extjs, extjs3, extjs-mvc

I want to create this parameter file so that I can send it to my web service.

```
var parms = {
  "quiz_id":"120",
  "owner_id":"1",
  "solver_id":"1",
   "answers":
    [
      {
  "answer_text" : "YES",
  "question_id" : "1"
      },
      {
  "answer_text" : "NO",
  "question_id" : "2"
      },
      {
  "answer_text" : "YES",
  "question_id" : "3"
      },
      {
  "answer_text" : "YES",
  "question_id" : "4"
      },
      {
  "answer_text" : "YES",
  "question_id" : "5"
      }
   ]
};
```

I am stuck with the contents inside of the answers. I don't know how to create it dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for serializing Javascript objects to JSON strings either you can use

```
JSON.stringify(Object);
```

which is available in most of the latest browers, else you can use ExtJS inbuilt method

```
Ext.encode(Object);
```

and for deserializing JSON string you can use `JSON.parse(JSONString)` or `Ext.decode(JSONString)`

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is to create your data as a javascript object and then use a Json "stringifier" to turn it into a json string, which can then be passed to your server.

This same problem was answered previously at [Serializing an object to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558518/how-to-serialise-on-object-to-json-in-javascript)

If you use jquery (and I highly recommend it as a very useful tool for all serious javascript programmers), there is a nice plugin that I use for passing json back and forth in Ajax calls. See http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

Comment: i am using extjs 3.4 for creating json and making ajax call for webservice

Comment: I just saw your comment and am not sure why the fact that you are using extjs excludes you from using a stringifier. If you don't want to bother with the JQuery overhead, then the stringifier from json.org is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object with array and some objects inside and then look at the `Ext.data.proxy.Server.encodeFilters()` method.

Comment: download ExtJs if you haven't yet. go to src/data/proxy. Check Server.js file

Comment: well.. I thought you were using 4 by looking at your tags. You still can download ExtJs 4.0 and see how it's done. Not sure if 3 has similar methods - I don't have much experience with 3

Comment: download ExtJs 4.0.7. go to src/data/proxy. Check Server.js file

Comment: can i use for loop inside js file