# Json string parsing issue

Tags: javascript, json

```
  var jsonString ="{ "
            jsonString += "name:" + Data.name+",";
            jsonString += "surname:"+ Data.surname+",";
            jsonString += "Address: " + Data.add;
            jsonString += "}"
```

I am creating following json string for the Ajax call.but when there is "," in the address field. it is giving me error. can anybody tell me proper way to create json string in javascript for ajax calls

Comment: Why not use jQuery with an object, or the [`JSON`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558518/how-to-serialise-on-object-to-json-in-javascript) package?

Comment: Put the data in quotes and escape all quotes in the data.

Comment: how to escape the quotes in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to generate your JSON string. It will automatically escape any character, where this is needed.

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify( Data );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify({
  'name': Data.name,
  'surname': Data.surname,
  'address': Data.add
});
```

Please note that @Sirko provided very similar answer. Please use his if you want to serialize all fields from 'Data' object. If not, use mine.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you create a json string like that in JavaScript? JSON or "**JavaScript** Object Notation". You can create an object and make it a JSON string with the built-in methods.

```
var data = {
  name: Data.name,
  surname: Data.surname,
  ...
};

var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: Is JSON.stringify supported on all the browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var jsonString ="{ ";
jsonString += "name:" + '"'+Data.name + '",';
jsonString += "surname:"+ '"'+ Data.surname + '",';
jsonString += "Address: " + '"'+ Data.add + '"';
jsonString += "}";
```

or you can use `JSON.stringify()` from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: You forgot to escape the quotes.