# print[ [object Object],[object Object]] to json array

Tags: javascript, json

I want to print `[object Object],[object Object]` to like wise `"[[{ 'x': '1', 'y': '0' }, { 'x': '2', 'y': '1' }]]";`
How it is possible in javascript

Comment: Have you attempted at doing this? Perhaps following this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558518/how-to-serialise-on-object-to-json-in-javascript ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a string representation of a JavaScript object, use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)