# How to convert arraylist of custom object in to json in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, json

I have a (java.util.List) List returned to the jag. That should be printed as a json .

```
   var storeForum = Packages.org.wso2.carbon.forum.registry.RegistryForumManager;

   var forum = new storeForum();

   var start = request.getParameter('start');
   var count = request.getParameter('count');

   var array =forum.fetchForumTopics(start,count, tenantDomainsArr, -1234, user.username);
```

*forum.fetchForumTopics* method returns

```
    List<customOjbect>
```

How to print it as a json. Didn't find anything useful on net.

Comment: You'll have to decide what you want, JSON is a dataformat for strings, an object is a native javascript structure of data, they are in no way the same thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558518/how-can-i-serialise-an-object-to-json-in-javascript. Your question appears to be answered here

Answer (score 1):

i'm not quite sure what a jag is - but you can use JSON.stringify() to convert an array of pairs or values into a JSON object

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

```
JSON.stringify(array)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It only gives "{}" as the output even though
returned list is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a java object, can you try this conversion using a java module that can convert the respective Object to JSON?.. You may have to import that module to the .jag (jaggery) file.

Comment: That'll work.But I wonder if there's a way to do this conversion with out having to import any java module.