# JavaScript - converting object key value pairs to JSON

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object with 6 key value pairs:

```
My_Type_1:"Vegetable"
My_Type_2:"Fruit"
My_Type_3:"Dessert"

My_Value_1: "Carrot"
My_Value_2: "Apple"
My_Value_3: "Cake"
```

I want to construct JSON out of the above object such that it generates the following:

```
[{"Vegetable":"Carrot"},{"Fruit":"Apple"},{"Dessert":"Cake"}]
```

**EDIT:**

```
for (j=0;j<3;j++)
{
    var tvArray = new Array();
    var sType = 'My_Type_'+j+1;
    var sValue = 'My_Value_'+j+1;
    tvArray['Type']  = JSObject[sType];
    tvArray['Value'] = JSObject[sValue];
}
```

The json.stringify doesn't produce the desired output as listed above.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: *"but it doesn't work"* Please tell us more.

Comment: Sorry.. I think the logic I have is screwed up.. So I removed it..

Comment: This question has been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558518/how-can-i-serialise-an-object-to-json-in-javascript

Comment: But that doesn't make the question better. The answer would be to iterate over the object, create new objects and push them onto an array. I assume you know how to do all of these things?

Comment: Put your code back plz. You have an error there. You need to put parenthesis around `(j + 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put parenthesis around `j + 1`. What you have now gives you `'My_Type_01'` and so on.

```
var obj = {
    My_Type_1:"Vegetable",
    My_Type_2:"Fruit",
    My_Type_3:"Dessert",

    My_Value_1: "Carrot",
    My_Value_2: "Apple",
    My_Value_3: "Cake"
};

var pairs = [], pair;
for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
   pair = {};
   pairs.push(pair);
   pair[obj['My_Type_' + (j+1)]] = obj['My_Value_' + (j+1)];
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(pairs));
```