# How to convert a javascript object to json

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to convert a JavaScript object to a json.

Practically I have created a website where you can upload a json, edit it and download it with your changes.

For convenience when I edit it creates a javascript object that will be converted at the end of the changes with `JSON.stringify`.

The problem is that the final Json should have the same characteristics as the initial one with the elements associated to the different key.

For example the first one can be this:

```
"tickets": {
    "use": "Valida",
    "useagain": "Valida di nuovo",
    "usetitle": "Convalida biglietto",
    "usemessage": "Vuoi convalidare il biglietto ora?",
    "purchaseconfirmtitle": "Confermi l\"acquisto?",
    "purchaseconfirmmessage": "Potrai convalidare il biglietto più tardi",
    "minutes": "Minuti",
}
```

The result must be like this:

```
"tickets": {
    "use": "Example",
    "useagain": "Example1",
    "usetitle": "Example2",
    "usemessage": "Example3,
    "purchaseconfirmtitle": "Example4",
    "purchaseconfirmmessage": "5",
    "minutes": "Minuti",
}
```

How do I make sure that all elements will be children of "ticket" (for example)?

Comment: you need to add more details to clarify...

Comment: have you tried `JSON.stringify` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I serialize an object to JSON in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558518/how-can-i-serialize-an-object-to-json-in-javascript)

Comment: your object is already a valid JSOn

Comment: You describe a process where the user can edit the object, so can't they change the structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to W3Schools(consider following example),

`var text = '{ "employees" : [' +
'{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" } ]}';`

Here is your object,

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

Here is the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp).

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: i don't know why but your link don't appear 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Its no big deal. [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: nope but in first look i didn't get it's a link. i think you trying to get the second element of `[JSON.stringify()]` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to compare two javascript object.

Try this url

http://procbits.com/2012/01/19/comparing-two-javascript-objects

is that what you are looking for?